# Monitoring azure storage bandwidth usage for each of my users

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an application that will give SAS tokens to registered users to upload and download directly from Azure storage. What is the best way to monitor the bandwidth for each of my users?

I have taken a look at the logs that Azure provides, and looking at things, a possible way is to bind the SAS token to the user's ip address, and then check the logs for the `<requester-ip-address>` field. However, this way doesn't seem so concrete as multiple users might have the same ip address.

Also, I see a `<request-id-header>` field which, according to the documentation, is an opaque value that uniquely identifies the request. However I don't see any way of getting the header value if the user directly communicates with azure storage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be:

- Using Copy Blob API: create a temporary file with user's username and generate a SAS token for user to download the file
- Remove the file after the expiry of the SAS token
- Check for the analytic logs in the Storage account; whether the blob was accessed, and whether the download was successful, and if not downloaded bytes
- If user failed to download the whole blob; you will see SASNetworkError in the log
- In the event of SASNetworkError; the log will contain the amount of data that was downloaded by the user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format *response-packet-size*). This will tell you the percentage of the download that completed right before the error.

Comment: Thank you, I have not thought about it this way. But would this cause an overhead if the file is huge, the user would have to wait awhile before their file becomes ready?

Comment: If you are copying within the account, it may be relatively quick (mostly instantaneous). However if the data is too big, I wouldn't use the Copy Blob API, and just use the original file for downloads as you initially planned.

Comment: But using the original file for downloads, we can't reliably track the bandwidth of the user?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to monitor the bandwidth for each of my users?

Based on my experience, we have no suitable way to do that. It seems that we couldn't get the bandwidth value. If you worry about the limition of azure storage, we could get the [Azure Storage limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets) from the azure official document.

> **Maximum Request Rate per storage account**   Blobs: 20,000 requests per second2 for blobs of any valid size (capped only by the account's ingress/egress limits)
>
> **Target throughput for single blob**  Up to 60 MB per second, or up to 500 requests per second

**Update:**

We could according  [Azure price calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) to adopt appropriate strategy to limit the cost for user.

[image]

Take [General-purpose Storage Accounts](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/storage-account-types-include.md) for example, the cost depends on Storage transactions and Capacity. If we want to limit the cost for the user. On my opinion, we could limit the **size*transaction** for the user.

- Create relationship for SAS tokens and user
- Get the `request uri` and `request-content-length` from the log and we also   count the request for user
- Use logic to control the **size*transaction** for user.

About Storage Analytics Log Format please refer to azure [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-log-format).

**Other related link:**

[Understanding Windows Azure Storage Billing – Bandwidth, Transactions, and Capacity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am more interested in how much money each user of my application is costing me. Because Azure storage charges for data that transfers out of their server.

Comment: If we want to limit cost for user, we could use our logic to control it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The main cost would be towards bandwidth, and we are working on tracking that. [Azure calculator with bandwidth](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=bandwidth).

Comment: When you say create relationship for SAS Tokens and users, do you mean that we store in the record in database, and then after the logs are ready, we will scan the log for any entries related to the SAS token, and extract the request-content-length?

Comment: You could log the user request-content value in the database and get the request-content-length from your interface.

Comment: If I have ahugefile.rar downloaded by many of my users, and there are some who download successfully, some halfway, and some totally failed, how do I know the bandwidth transferred for each of my users individually?

Comment: If the user fails to download the blob, you will see SASNetworkError in the analytic logs.